# The P.W.L.H system

Tags: riddle

Ever heard about this system?

> A system that determines a part of your life.
>
> A system that is comparable with TCP.
>
> The system, which is the host, and the client.
>
> A system that runs BrainOS.
>
> A system that will only connect to only one client at a time, but is still connected with every human existing.
>
> A system that calculates two variables: H and L
>
> A system that will calculate L with the following formula: L≥0, and H with: H>1
>
> A system that is very dynamic.
>
> And fun fact: The client will never know these variables. The client will only feel it.

What is this system doing?

HINT #1

> The variables represents a social element of human life

HINT #2

> "Nobody should die alone"

HINT #3

A piece of code, using the H and L variables from this system, translated into C#. The code would set how many relations a person would get. Please ignore the "> 1" error, which would fail in real C#.

> int totalPeopleKnown = 30, int familyMembers = 3;
>  if(H > 10 && L <= 3){ Person.Relations = 0; }
>  else if(H ≤ 10  && L > 10){ Person.Relations >= 1; }
>  else{ Person.Relations = 1;}

HINT #4

> Think about your dog

HINT #5

> One part of Talal_Sharaa's explanation was fully  correct and could solve this puzzle easily. Unfortunately was Talal_Sharaa's answer not the correct one. This system calculates something. But 'what?' is the question here.

This is the last hint I'll give, if nobody asks for it.

Alright, one hint more. Just because I want this puzzle solved.

> Styx's answer would be correct if he did not think about himself

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The answer is:

> The system calculates how many people love you, and how many will hate you

Explanation:

A system that determines a part of your life

> If you have a lot of people that love you, you will be a different person than someone with alot of hate

A system that is comparable with TCP

> Explained in riddle it self. The Host is this system, and the client/listener is the person

The system, which is the host, and the client

A system that runs BrainOS

> Some funny name I came up with to express the brain

A system that will only connect to only one client at a time, but is still connected with every human existing.

> The system will calculate it's variables individually, but it still has to know which persons are going to love/hate that person

A system that calculates two variables: H and L

> H = Hate, L = Love

A system that will calculate L with the following formula: L≥0, and H with: H>1

> L is equal or greater than 0, since there is the possibility that no-one loves you (it's rare though) and H is greater than 1, because there is always someone who doesn't like you.

A system that is very dynamic

> These variables will change during lifetime. L could have been 10 when someone is 6 yrs old, but it could be 25 when someone is 16 yrs old.

And fun fact: The client will never know these variables. The client will only feel it.

> You will never know the value of these variables. You can only guess it. But you can feel it. Having friends and family makes you happy. Having alot of haters could lead you to a depression.

Hints explained:

Hint #1

The variables represents a social element of human life

> Having friends and family is a social element of life

Hint #2

"Nobody should die alone"

> If love is 0, you will die alone which is a nightmare for alot of people

Hint #3

int totalPeopleKnown = 30, int familyMembers = 3;
 if(H > 10 && L <= 3){ Person.Relations = 0; }
 else if(H ≤ 10 && L > 10){ Person.Relations >= 1; }
 else{ Person.Relations = 1;}

> I'am not going full depth into this code but if the H value is high and the L value is low, you'll probably won't get any relationships. And turning it.around will get you a lot of relationships

Hint #4

Think about your dog

> One: Dogs normally love you, two: Men's best friend is the dog.

Hint #5 not going to explain that one

Hint #6

> Styx was looking it the opposite way (Person => Community). That's why he struggled with the formula. As I told: Don't think about yourself just means "Try to look it from a different perspective (Community => Person)"

Answer (score 3):

The system is:

> Thinking and taking decisions

A system that determines a part of your life.

> The system determines which university you go to
>  Which job you take
>  Which Man/Woman you marry and etc....

A system that runs BrainOS.

> This system is responsible for Thinking and taking decisions
> and these are major parts of BrainOS

A system that will only connect to only one client at a time, but is still connected with every human existing.

> Every thought you think, Every decision you make affects other people in your circle or in the world...

A system that calculates two variables: H and L

> Hate and Love

A system that is very dynamic.

> Always thinking of the alternatives and the solutions for any problem

And fun fact: The client will never know these variables. The client will only feel it.

> In love for example one doesn't know why he love but he can feel it..

Comment: Not the answer I am looking for. The formula plays a big role for the answer

Comment: Do wanna note though that some of the explanations are correct and should be used in the final answer

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess:

> Consciousness

A system that determines a part of your life.

> You decide how to live your life based on your consciousness

A system that is comparable with TCP.

> You don't make a decision until your consciousness "negotiates the parameters" and "approves" it (also could be seen as a request to a server)

The system, which is the host, and the client.

A system that runs BrainOS.

> The system is in the brain, making it both the host and the client

A system that will only connect to only one client at a time, but is still connected with every human existing.

> Our consciousness only affects us as individuals, but we all have it (not sure about this one)

A system that calculates two variables: H and L

> Based on the dog hint I think L stands for Love (dogs love you unconditionally), that would make sense that the H is Hate

A system that will calculate L with the following formula: L≥0, and H with: H>1

> Here's where the Love Hate variables don't make sense to me anymore. If L was love then, it should be >1 as you always love yourself (even though people say they hate themselves, it's pretty much in your nature to love yourself. If H was hate then it should be >=0 as you could hate no one, or as many as you feel like, but it's not necessarily that you hate at least 1.

A system that is very dynamic.

> Calculations in the brain happen very fast and one's consciousness may change quite drastically in the light of new events

And fun fact: The client will never know these variables. The client will only feel it.

> Pretty sure the variables are emotions as you can't really measure them, just feel their intensity, which again doesn't really match hint 3, because you know how many people you love or hate..

Answer (score 3):

A weird answer coming from my BrainOS

> Cerebro from X men

A system that is comparable with TCP.

> Prof X uses this to connect with every human in the world, same like the protocol is used

The system, which is the host, and the client.

> Cerebro is connected to both Prof x and all the human beings, making it a single system with both host and client in it

A system that runs BrainOS.

> Uses Prof X brainy mind powers.

A system that will only connect to only one client at a time, but is still connected with every human existing.

> Connects to Prof X but still connected to everyone indirectly

A system that calculates two variables: H and L

> maybe a reference to difference between humans and non humans while scanning with cerebro

And fun fact: The client will never know these variables. The client will only feel it.

> Human beings generally don't know when the Prof uses the machine. But he can manipulate feelings using the machine

Comment: Oh just saw the new hints which talk about dogs and emotions...i think you can count my answer out then

Comment: I doubt this riddle has anything to do with Cerebro, but the correlation is very impressive...

Comment: Haha, wrong answer but the most impressive one.